# What exactly happens when -O3 is set

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have the following code :

```
int main()
{
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        //do something
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code using 'gcc -o file file.c' command, it is getting executed in 244 milli seconds and when I execute the same code using 'gcc -O3 file.c -o file' it is getting executed in 0 milli seconds(very little time which is shown as zero). I could not understand what optimization is done by -O3 flag in such a way that we get lot of speed in execution.

Any link,doc or an explaination regarding '-O3' optimization(apart from gcc.gnu.org, which I have seen and found the info given there is not sufficient to provide me a decent explaination and insight of what goes on) is much appreciated.

Comment: perhaps it realises no side effect of the loop is used and substitues a nop

Comment: Provide us a assembly code generated by gcc if you want to find out what happened underhood. Right now we can just guess. Also I think, that `//do something` has a meaning in this case.

Comment: It depends a lot on what *do something* does!

Comment: To *really* know what's going on you should probably be knowledgeable in compiler and code-generation theory and practice.

Comment: To have a best understanding, please refer to Robert Love's answer on Quora, link is [When should you use the different GCC optimization flags (e.g. -O2)?](https://www.quora.com/When-should-you-use-the-different-GCC-optimization-flags-e-g-O2)

Comment: The compiler likely realizes that `//do something` does the same thing lots of times, and that the result will be the same if it is done only once, or even zero times if you do not use the result.

Comment: Add the `-Q --help=optimizers` options to the gcc command line to see the optimizations it has chosen.

Comment: Look at the assembly output (`gcc -S -O3 file.c`).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately we need to know what 
`//do something` does.  You should paste your exact code that you used because technically the return statement would be executed as the body of the loop.

If you had something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int junkInteger = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 5 ;i++)
    {
        junkInteger++;  // just to have a body
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With optimization, your loop may become unrolled like such and would thus cause your code size to become larger.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int junkInteger = 0;

    // loop gets unrolled
    junkInteger++;
    junkInteger++;
    junkInteger++;
    junkInteger++;
    junkInteger++;
    return 0;
}
```

When the loop gets unrolled, the low level assembly/machine code does not have to perform a Load, Store, Compare, and Branch to manage the loop.

You should try your code again with this:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with both optimization on and off and examine the file sizes and even put in the compile option to generate assembly code.  Usually with optimizations enabled, code size can become larger due to loop unrolls.  Although the code could be optimized out since the body does nothing.  Perhaps use a volatile loop counter to ensure it is not optimized out.